# A Way To Fix Shrunken Clothes

Tags: clothing, laundry

When I started washing my clothes a long time ago, I washed my mom's hoodie (yes, it is this critical!) and I didn't know that putting it into the dryer would shrink it. Is there a way to undo this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can tell us what the material is and estimate the extent of the shrinkage—how much smaller than the intended size (%). Please update (Edit) your question with any additional information. Thanx,

Comment: Extra information is welcome but do not get your hopes up. This kind of shrinking is mostly permanent.

Answer (score 2):

**Best Way To Fix Shrunken Clothes**

There is one way to fix it!

Buy a new one.

Done this a few times. I am a tailor by trade and will admit my own ***”[fubar](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=F.U.B.A.R)”*** mistakes.

Wool that is once shrunk, can not be restored to it’s normal size. The weave in general will not allow any possible restoration. The weave often shrink irregularly from top to bottom and then left to right.

Bought friends many sweaters in the process because of this. I learned my lesson.

In the future, wash, in cold water and let dry on a cloth line if possible.

Comment: you know what shrunk? an original Barcelona jersey :(, can that type of material be restored?

Comment: @Isaac750 please post more information, in the question. First it's a hoodie, now it's a jersey. Did you perhaps stretch it by wearing, not shrink by washing?

Comment: oh, pfff, whoops, right, about the hoodie, I forgot... yes, the question is about the hoodie, I shouldn't ask that in the comment section... No. I try to not stretch my clothes at all...